# Pass variable into AppleScript from python

Tags: python, applescript, osascript

Can someone show me how to pass a variable into an Applescript using osascript in python?  I've seen some documentation/samples on doing this but I'm not understanding it at all.

Here is my python code:

```
# I want to pass this value into my apple script below
myPythonVariable = 10

cmd = """
    osascript -e '
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        if "MyApp" is in activeApp then
            set stepCount to myPythonVariableIPassIn

            repeat with i from 1 to stepCount
                DoStuff...
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
    '
    """
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502836/pass-and-receive-values-between-python-script-and-applescript

Comment: In the solution to that one he's passing in '/Setup.scpt'.  I was hoping to inline the applescript code right in my python code rather than having a ton of separate .scpt files I have to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation with the **+** operator

```
myPythonVariable = 10
cmd = """
    osascript -e '
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        if "MyApp" is in activeApp then
            set stepCount to """ + str(myPythonVariable) + """

            repeat with i from 1 to stepCount
                -- do something
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
    '
    """
```

---

Or, string formatting with the **{}** :

```
myPythonVariable = 10
cmd = """
    osascript -e '
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        if "MyApp" is in activeApp then
            set stepCount to {0}

            repeat with i from 1 to stepCount
                -- do something
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
    '
    """.format(myPythonVariable)
```

**{0}** is the place-holder for the first variable, **{1}** is the place-holder for the second variable, ....

For multiple variables:

> .format(myPythonVariable, var2, var3)

---

Or, string formatting with the **%s** operator

```
myPythonVariable = 10
cmd = """
    osascript -e '
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        if "MyApp" is in activeApp then
            set stepCount to %s

            repeat with i from 1 to stepCount
                -- do something
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
    '
    """ % myPythonVariable
```

For multiple variables:

> % (myPythonVariable, var2, var3)