# Change directory using applescript using a path variable defined in Python file

Tags: python, macos, applescript, osascript

I am trying to use a variable defined in python file in an embedded applescript. I want the path in currentpath to be appended where I mentioned the variable in the osascript statement.

I have tried all the methods given in the link and some other links too but none of them work: [Pass variable into AppleScript from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185160/pass-variable-into-applescript-from-python)

```
import os
import sys
currentpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
com  = ("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "afplay {0}/Sounds/storm-9s.mp3"'""".format(currentpath))
os.system(com)
```

All the tricks lead me to the same errors and I am not sure if the problem is with my python code or applescript.

```
A94HDBSGHHHD:~ user$ afplay /Sounds/storm-9s.mp3
Unspecified exception
A94HDBSGHHHD:~ user$
```

Update: My application requires to play multiple sound files simultaneously. Using subprocesses requires my script to pipeline the sound files and play the second file only when the first file is played completely. Thus I have to start multiple terminals to play the sounds together.
e.g. My code plays a.mp3 and then before it completes playing, my code decides to play b.mp3. So it should start playing b.mp3 without stopping a.mp3 and play them both simultaneously till a.mp3 stops when the file is over and then b.mp3 stops when the file is done playing.

Comment: Question: what you are effectively doing here is using python to call osascript to script terminal to run a shell script. Why not just call 'afplay' directly from python? see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code

Comment: I have tried it. Please read the update on my issue. I cannot play multiple files simultaneously  with it.

Comment: You can get python to detach and run processes simultaneously, but I'll add an answer that discusses both ways.

Comment: Can you please share how?

Comment: see my answer below. I'm not really a python guru, so I've just linked a couple of other questions/answers from SO, but the procedure seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the best approach to this problem would be to avoid AppleScript entirely and run the 'afplay' command straight from python. If you read these two Stack Overflow questions:

- [How to detach a process called by subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538651/how-to-detach-a-program-ran-by-subprocess-call)
- [Running subprocesses in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450788/python-running-subprocess-in-parallel)

You'll see you should be able to use `popen` to run these sound files simultaneously.

If you really want an AppleScript solution, then I suggest you forget about scripting Terminal and use `do shell script` instead. That is basically the same as running shell commands straight from AppleScript, without the overhead of Terminal.app. That would look like this:

```
com  = """osascript -e 'do shell script "afplay {0}/Sounds/storm-9s.mp3 &> /dev/null &"'""".format(currentpath)
```

or if you wanted to get adventuresome you could chain them all together like so:

```
com  = """osascript -e 'do shell script "afplay {0}/Sounds/storm-9s.mp3 &> /dev/null &"' -e 'do shell script "afplay {1}/Sounds/storm-9s.mp3 &> /dev/null &"'""".format(path0, path1)
```

Assuming that currentpath (path0/path1) gives a correct prefix, this should work; the `&> /dev/null &` bit tells `do shell script` to detach the process and return immediately. But this is, again, circuitous: you're telling python to tell a shell to tell AppleScript to tell a shell to do something, and every extra context shift creates an opportunity for something to go wrong.

Comment: the first command gives me below error "47:48: syntax error: Expected expression but found “>”. (-2741)
tab 1 of window id 5286" The second command cannot be used as which mp3 files will be played depends on user input and is decided in real-time. I am just making sure how the code plays it.

Comment: sorry, I misplaced a quotation mark. I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: I tried using popen and it worked as expected. Thank you so much!